Unnumbered critical note in reledmac
Good afternoon!
I am currently writing my dissertation using Lyx (I know, it's not the best way, but I am not confident enough yet to work on something without Lyx's interface), and I am working on a critical edition of multiple poems with reledmac.
At first I was using ledgroups to have the apparatus immediately below its poem, but that didn't help me with poems that took more than one page (let's say there's a 25 lines poem, the first 20 lines are on a page and the remaining 5 lines are on the following page: the apparatus of course was after the last 5 lines, and I couldn't figure out how to print the apparatus of the first 20 lines in the previous page). I ended up deciding to have multiple apparatus at the end of the page, and this solution works well for me.
The only problem is that I would like to add some sort of "title" for each apparatus with the number of the relevant poem. I found out that I could manage the problem by adding a critical note at the beginning of the poem with the poem number in bold, but if I do this the note is preceded by the line number, and I don't want it to.
Here's an example of my code:
    %% LyX 2.3.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm}
\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E},parapparatus]{reledmac}
\lineation{pstart}
\linenummargin{outer}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A,B,C,D,E]
\Xsymlinenum[A,B,C,D,E]{|}
\Xnolemmaseparator
\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$}
\Xafterrule{0pt}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\AtEveryPend{\vskip2\baselineskip}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

%This is something that I simply copied and pasted to have the note series 'renew' whenever they reached the series E, so that I can just type \edtext{whatever}{\nota{whatever}}  and have one series of note for each \pstart (poem). I have no clue how it works but it works for me  
\makeatletter% We need to use command with @
  % Two counters: one for left and one for right
  \newcounter{mynotelevel}%
    \renewcommand{\themynotelevel}{\Alph{mynotelevel}}% Print the counter as a letter

  % Following lines are called at each \pstart
  \AtEveryPstartCall{%
          \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%Step counter
          \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%No more than E series (5)
            \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}%If more than J => restart to A (1)
          }{}%
            \global\letcs{\nota}{\themynotelevel footnote}%And let mynote be equal to <X>footnote, where <X> is the current level \letcs is defined by etoolbox which called by reledmac

  }
  % This code is called when beginnings of each pstart are printed
  \AtEveryPstart{%
        \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%Step counter
        \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%No more than E series (5)
          \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}}{}%% If more than E => restart to A (1)
          \seriesatend{\themynotelevel}% The series should be at the end
   }

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart

\centering{\LARGE{\textbf{LIBER EPIGRAMMATON}}}

\pend

\pstart

\textbf{1 – First poem}\skipnumbering

This is the

\edtext{first}{\nota{primo}}

poem.

Line 4.

Line \edtext{5}{\lemma{}\nota{}five}.

I also need to sometimes use Greek, as in \textgreek{τόπος}.

\pend

\pstart

\textbf{2 – Secondo poem}\skipnumbering\\

This is the 

\edtext{second}{\nota{secondo}} 

poem.

Line \edtext{4}{\lemma{}\nota{four}}

Line 5.

\pend

\pstart

\textbf{3 – Third poem}\skipnumbering\\

This is the

\edtext{third}{\nota{terzo}}

poem

\edtext{Line}{\nota{verso}} 4

Line 5.

\pend

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\numberlinefalse

\pstart

\centering{\LARGE{\textbf{TRADUZIONE}}}

\pend

\pstart

\textbf{1 – Primo}

This is the translation of the first poem.

 \pend

\newpage

\pstart

\textbf{2 – Secondo}

This is the translation of the second poem.

 \pend

\pstart

\textbf{3 – Terzo}

This is the translation of the third poem.

 \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}

\Pages
\end{document}

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:

As you can see, I basically would like to put a single number in the point with the red arrow at the beginning of each apparatus.
I hope I have been clear, sorry but I'm new to all this and I'm trying to learn along!
Thanks to those who will answer.

Welcome to TeX SE! Can you add the code for a minimal example allowing people to reproduce the issue?

Thanks! Yes, sorry, as I said I am new to all of this. I added an example of my code and a clearer example of what I want to achieve. Unfortunately I know close to nothing about this, so I have been copying stuff I found here in my Lyx preamble to add stuff I need to my document, and apart from the problem I explain in the question it works for me (although it's probably confusing and badly written for those who actually know what they're doing).

Hi! I took the liberty to remove a couple of things in your code that made it buggy and not compilable: one extra } and an extra \else and \fi that didn't follow an \if (from a code block you copied from elsewhere)

In case you haven't solved your issue in the meantime, here's my solution.
The easiest and most "customizable" way to achieve this would be by writing an \edtext footnote, just as you did, but specify that it shouldn't print a line number. It is "customizable" because you do this manually and at the poem level, so you can choose what text (or number) to input.
Use the option [nonum] right before the footnote:
\edtext{text}{\lemma{}\Afootnote[nonum]{footnote}}

or in your specific case
\edtext{4}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{four}}

(§ 6.2.2 of the reledmac documentation)
A footnote typeset this way will leave some whitespace before your text input, where the line number + line num separator would have been, i.e. at the beginning of the line. The default value is 1em of whitespace. You can change or suppress this amount via
\Xinplaceofnumber[<s>]{0pt}      % remove [] to apply to all series

(§ 7.4.15 of the documentation)
